# JAXB Unmarshalling not working. Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal an XML.

This is what my XML looks like

```
<DeviceInventory2Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<DeviceInventory2Result xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Obj123 xmlns="">
     <Id>1</Id>
     <Name>abc</Name>
  </Obj123>
  <Obj456 xmlns="">
  .
  .
  .
```

I am trying to get Id and Name under Obj123.  However when I run my unmarshal command I get the following error.

```
An Error:  javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://tempuri.org/", local:"DeviceInventory2Response"). Expected elements are (none)
```

My code looks like this in the main class:

```
Obj123 myObj123 = (Obj123) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);
```

And my class for Obj123 looks like this:

```
package com.myProj.pkg;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlRootElement(name="Obj123")
public class Obj123 {

  private String Id;
  private String Name;

  public String getId() {
    return Id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

I thought by setting my XMLRootElement that I should be able to skip the first 2 lines of my XML but that doesn't seem to be happening.  Any ideas?

Edit:

This is how my JAXB Context is made:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Obj123 obj123 = (Obj123) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);
```

Comment: You should get rid of the first two lines. Or use another object 'DeviceInventory2Result' make it a root element and add the Obj123 as the child to it.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot edit the XML at all.  Is making another class the only way to do it?  No way to ignore them?

Comment: I guess, you can ignore the child elements, but not the parent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JAXB implementations will try to match on the root element of the document (not on a child element). 
If you want to unmarshal to the middle of an XML document then you can parse the document with StAX advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the desired element and then unmarshal that.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

### UPDATE

> now I am getting the following error. An Error:
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
>   [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"Obj123"). Expected elements are (none)].

A `JAXBContext` only knows about the classes you tell it about.  Instead of:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
```

You need to do:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Obj123.class);
```

Comment: Ok cool.  I went through that and it def. seems to be what I was looking for.  However, once I implemented it I got the following error:  Method getLocalName() cannot be called for START_DOCUMENT event.

Any Ideas why that would happen?

Comment: @CameronJones - You need to advance past the START_DOCUMENT event before you call getLocalName().

Comment: Ah okay.  I missed your first .nextTag() call.  I fixed that but now I am getting the following error.  An Error:  javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Obj123"). Expected elements are (none)].  I think this is more of an issue with my Obj123 class and not with the Unmarshling process, though.

Comment: @CameronJones - How are you creating your `JAXBContext`?

Comment: @CameronJones - I have updated my answer with the information you need to solve that problem.

Comment: Perfect.  I was unaware of that with the JAXBContext. Must have missed it in the documentation.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 20):

I solved the problem by adding

`@XmlRootElement(name="abc_xxx")`  to the Root class.
*(where abc_XXX is the root tag of your XML)*

The JAXB classes generated by eclipse didn't add this annotation to my root class.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing solution. I wonder why this annotation is not added automatically?

Comment: Thanks, this also was the solution for me

Comment: Solved the problem by generating XMLRootElement, using the solution by Rasto here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582550/want-xmlrootelement-in-classes-generated-by-jaxb2-maven-plugin

Answer (score 10):

Use ObjectFactory class instead like

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
try {
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JAXBElement<ObjectFactory> applicationElement = null;
try {
    applicationElement = (JAXBElement<ObjectFactory>)
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(Thread.currentThread().getClass()
        .getResourceAsStream(fileName));
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Try this and will resolve above problem. My problem has been resolved.

Comment: `JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);` is correct, but you stil lhave to cast the resulting object to `(JAXBElement<Obj123>)`, not to `(JAXBElement<ObjectFactory>)`. Good tip, though